# can xdiagnose tools can help me with troubleshoot suspend/resume on my laptop

Tags: suspend, nouveau

I've found a tool called xdiagnose on my 12.04LTS, but no documentation.
I have a  Dell Latitude laptop -- will this help me resolve suspend and resume issues that might be related to nvidia and nouveau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdiagnose` can be quite a useful tool for some issues concerning graphics cards, although not particularly for suspend/resume issues as they are to do with the ACPI implementation of your laptop. There isn't a manpage for `xdiagnose` and the `--help` option relays a pretty terse selection of commands. However, the utility is really used for diagnosing and repairing Xorg issues, even though it could be the case that the Xorg server might be locking up on resume.

You can use `xdiagnose -v &` to track X errors in a general way and let it run in the background, and the 'extra graphics..' option in the pop-up screen (see screenshot) can be ticked to send more graphics debug messages to `dmesg`. Even though this information doesn't concern suspend/resume directly, the results might indirectly be useful if X is freezing on suspend or resume.

[image]

You can get information regarding ACPI by using grep to search `dmesg`, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` for ACPI, suspend, and hibernate errors.

There are also a lot of references to Dell Latitude laptops on [Ubuntuforums](http://www.ubuntuforums.org), so there should be some useful information there; but to answer your **specific** question, `xdiagnose` isn't really that useful for diagnosing suspend/resume issues. See this [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) page and [this one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend) for a very useful and general account of how to debug resume/suspend problems.